# kotlin SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 3000) from /192.168.0.66 (port 35314) after 10000ms

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

This has been posted a lot but I haven't come across any solution that would work for me.
I have a Flask server + Kotlin client. I am trying to do simple get request from my local rest Api.
what i did: 
1 Devices are on the same Wifi, (checked in ipconfig) 
2 I checked the ipv4 on ipconfig (it's the same) 
3 I tried running my phone on mobile hotspot and then accessing URL 
4 I tried adb reverse. 
5 I tried disabling windows10 firewall it didn't help.

I works on my emulator but not on the device.
This is my `.kt` file

```
class Constants {

    companion object{

        const val BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.185:3000"

    }
}
```

All the code is available here on my previous post ->
 [flask + retrofit in kotlin cannot acces API endpoint with IP address (Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:5000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858855/flask-retrofit-in-kotlin-cannot-acces-api-endpoint-with-ip-address-failed-to/68859129#68859129)

[image]

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it it's necessary to  ad `"/"` in .baseUrl()

```
private val retrofit  by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL + "/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

}
```